# What happens when giving a backwards range (to yank) in Vim?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, range

If you have:

```
minimum
working
exampl[e]
```

with `[]` representing your cursor, and issue `:.,-2y`, Vim will tell
you "Backwards range given" and prompt you to swap. If you don't swap it
seems to cancel the command.

I'd like to understand the difference between `:.,-2y` and `:-2,.y`, as
well as what happens when you say "no" to the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to understand the difference between `:.,-2y` and `:-2,.y`,

The former is simply wrong, because, as per `:h E493`,

> A range should have the lower line number first.  If this is not the case, Vim
> will ask you if it should swap the line numbers.

Although sensible, this actually deviates from [POSIX, that says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_10)

> It shall be an error if the first address is greater than the second address.

---

> What happens when you say "no" to the prompt?

Nothing significant in this case. [Read the source](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/aca12fd89b082dd9cc12ae085a84f1805747bbdf/src/ex_docmd.c#L2154).

Comment: Thanks for the [tip to use Codidact](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/30440/quas%c3%admodo).

Comment: Great to learn that someone followed the trail!